# Where is the best place for banner AD?

Tags: mobile, android, games, advertisement

When users quit the game, I show fullScreen AD.

But I think it's not enough.

Is it correct to add a banner AD at bottom of screen (between those little circle buttons)?

[image: Hit When White!]

Comment: We're going to need a little more context to properly answer this question.

Comment: What for example? tell me everything you what's know.

Comment: What type of game, is this a browsergame? Or is this add going to be much like what Steam does, after closing an actual game on a PC?

Comment: Full screen ad is not enough? No problem, just use popups with loud sounds saying "your computer has viruses", blinking images with hot chicks so you can attract attention. Trust me this way your users will surely notice your ad!

Comment: @MJB it's a flat Android game named "Hit When White!". And available in 2player and 4player mode.

Comment: @KristiyanLukanov haha, cool. No, I want something that make money but user numbers is more important for me.

Comment: Ideally, you might consider doing some A/B testing here... put the ad in one place for half your users, and somewhere else for the other half, and see which results in the most click-throughs. (Of course, you will also need a way to collect and analyse that data, without violating your users' privacy.)

Comment: @iMohammadreza Hope you got the joke. Well we can only guess what will be better for you. As *scottishwildcat* advised you should A/B test different variations of Ad presentation. Then you will surely know what works best in your specific situation. Good luck.

Comment: @scottishwildcat Aw, a good idea. Thanks for your advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mention your intentions that what you expect from the users.

- If you badly want users to tap on your ad **(intentionally or unintentionally)** you can place it between the buttons. The present generation using the smart phones are aware of the banner ads and they'll probably be careful. But the older users might just press it mistakenly and that's where you hit the target! For younger users it could be annoying and distracting and they might just uninstall the game, or won't come back if the ad is too close to the buttons they have to use constantly.
- But on the other hand, if you want to display an ad for the motive of promotion and not expecting users to tap it **unintentionally** then that won't be a nice place. You can shift the buttons up and keep a separate place for the banner ad below it.

Comment: Wow, a complete answers. So for me making monkey with this game is important but users are more important. And now full screen ad when users quit the game is enough, agree?

Comment: Yes, full screen ad is definitely a better option! Because It is tested that users don't like getting distracted in middle of the games or anything they are doing on the app. Once they finish a level or game, they have option to go with the ad or stick to the game. You can make the 'Close' button small so that people click on that ad while closing it (cheap trick though), and you will be making money by keeping your users undistracted.

Also, if it's a new game, get audience first. Once you have people addicted to your game, you'll have more audience to click on the ads.

Comment: Stars and reviews on the app stores are genuinely by the users, don't forget :) . So keep users intact by providing ad-free game, get audience, make them addicted, than ad ads!

Answer (score 0):

You can place the ad between the buttons as bottom area of the screen will be in more focus because of these two buttons there. Also, I don't see an issue of being clicked unwillingly as user knows which area of the screen represents the button. Logically, this is like clicking a button on the Physical device say a calculator.

Comment: Now, I think game with no banner ad is better. Thanks for you complete anwser